# How to get image files from subdirectories within a directory

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In matlab i want to access all the images of the extension ".hdr" from subdirectories which in turn are in a directory. And consequently all the image-names must be returned in a cell with one row and many columns, depending upon the number of images.I already used 'getAllFile' but I couldn't get the desired results. Please help me with any other idea. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, you have a few options. If this program is interacting with a user try this:

```
[filelist path] = uigetfile('.hdr', 'MultiSelect', 'on')
for ii =1:numel(filelist)
    filedir = fullfile(path, filelist{ii};
    % Do whatever you want with each file here.
end
```

In the case above, filelist is the cell array you mentioned in your question. If this isn't what you need, let me know, and I'll add another option.